# How can I make a dropdown menu based that only shows options for a certain cell?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with recipes and another sheet with ingredient and available products from different suppliers. I would like to create drop-down menu's so that someone can choose the exact product that corresponds to the ingredient in the recipe.

Here is a table with an example of a simple recipe and the eventual product drop-down:

| **Ingredients** | **Product choice** |
| --- | --- |
| **Bread** |  |
| **Hamburger** |  |
| **Cheese** |  |
| **Bacon** |  |

And here is a table example of the ingredients with possible products:

| **Ingredient** | **Product 1** | **Product 2** | **Product 3** | **Product 4** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Bread** | Dist 1 - Hamburger Bun | Dist 2 - Potato Roll |  |  |
| **Hamburger** | Dist 1 - Black Angus | Dist 1 - Mushroom | Dist 2 - Black Angus | Dist 2 - Vegan |
| **Cheese** | Dist 1 - Cheddar | Dist 2 - Gouda | Dist 3 - Blue |  |
| **Bacon** | Dist 1 - Smoked bacon | Dist 1 - Bacons cubes | Dist 1 - Vegan Bacon |  |

What I would ideally like to have is then the drop-down menu that gives me only the available products for the different ingredients. Something like this:

| **Ingredients** | **Product choice** |
| --- | --- |
| **Bread** | - Dist 1 - Hamburger Bun - Dist 2 - Potato Roll |
| **Hamburger** | - Dist 1 - Black Angus - Dist 1 - Mushroom - Dist 2 - Black Angus - Dist 2 - Vegan |
| **Cheese** | - Dist 1 - Cheddar - Dist 2 - Gouda - Dist 3 - Blue |
| **Bacon** | - Dist 1 - Smoked bacon - Dist 1 - Bacons cubes - Dist 1 - Vegan Bacon |

Now I understand how to make the lists, but not how to combine and INDEX MATCH like function to do this to create the lists, and doing it all by hand would take an impossible amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your products table is in `G1:K5` (with headers in row 1), and that the first ingredient for which you wish to apply the validation is in `A2`, first **make sure that the active cell within the worksheet is somewhere in row 2** and then go to Name Manager and define *MyVal* as:

`=LET(ζ,INDEX($H$2:$K$5,MATCH($A2,$G$2:$G$5,0),),INDEX(ζ,1):INDEX(ζ,COUNTA(ζ)))`

After which you can apply the following formula as a Data Validation List to cell `B2`:

`=MyVal`

This validation can be then copied down to `B3`, `B4`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. It says that the formula contains unrecognized text, and that "the source evaluates to an error". I take it it refers to the `ζ`.

Comment: You mean when you added the formula to the *Refers to:* box in Name Manager? There is nothing wrong with that symbol. Suggest you re-check that you entered it correctly.

Comment: Was definitely some error in my references. Thank you so much for this amazing answer!